# All solutions to underdetermined polynomial system

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations

\begin{align*}
\alpha\overline{\beta} + \overline{\alpha}\beta + q\lvert\alpha\rvert^2=0\\
\alpha\overline{\beta} + \overline{\alpha}\beta + q\lvert\beta\rvert^2=0
\end{align*}
where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}^\times$ and $0<q\leq 2$.

The equations are real, so what we have here is a system of 2 equations with 4 unknowns.

I know that some solutions are given by the following two families
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \alpha_1 + i\alpha_2 \\
\beta &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(q\alpha_1 \pm \sqrt{4-q^2}\alpha_2\right)
-\frac{i}{2}\left(q\alpha_2 \mp \sqrt{4-q^2}\alpha_1\right)
\end{align*}

Is there any way of knowing whether this parametrizes all solutions?

My limited knowledge of algebraic geometry didn't help much, but if there is an algebro-geometric argument, could you maybe point me to a resource? Thanks.

Comment: From the equations it follows that $|a|=|b|$. Therefore $b=ae^{it}$. Putting this in the first equation gives $q|a|^2+2|a|^2\cos(t)=0$. Therefore, $\cos(t)=-q/2$. Therefore, for each solution for $t$ one gets a solution of the form $a\neq0, b=ae^{it}$.

Comment: Didn't even think of that! Thank you. So the solutions I had were all, after all.